# NodeJS never call my bearer strategy

Tags: mysql, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, bearer-token

I try to secure my api end-points by Oauth2 and nodeJS. I follow all example provided in Github page of Oauth2orize and customize db to retrieve data in MySQL server.
Tokens are stored in DB, associated with an uid's user profile.

Finaly, when I call my URL /api/userinfo, my bearer stategy was not called, no output in my console (even the console.log).

Please find the code bellow:

```
app.get('/api/userinfo', user.info);

exports.info = [
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    // req.authInfo is set using the `info` argument supplied by
    // `BearerStrategy`.  It is typically used to indicate scope of the token,
    // and used in access control checks.  For illustrative purposes, this
    // example simply returns the scope in the response.
    res.json("Hello")
  }
]

passport.use(new BearerStrategy({},
  function(accessToken, done) {
    console.log("gell");
    db.accessTokens.find(accessToken, function(err, token) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!token) { return done(null, false); }
      db.users.find(token.userID, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        var info = { scope: '*' }
        console.log(user.cn)
        done(null, user, info);
      });
    });
  }
));
```

Any ideas why this strategy was not called ? How can I debug this situation?

Answer (score 1):

All this time, but lets answer:

First, try to name your strategy, It is what I do:

```
passport.use('user-bearer', new BearerStrategy(
  function(accessToken, done) {
    jwt.verify(accessToken, config.secrets.session, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) { return done(null, false, err); }

      // On future, scopes can ve taken from token.
      var info = {
        scope: '*'
      };
      done(null, decoded, info);
    });
  }
));
```

Later, you can validate like:

```
export function isAuthenticated() {
  return passport.authenticate('user-bearer', {
    session: false
  });
}
```

On my case I am using a stateless token, is this why I am using jwt web token.

This `isAuthenticated` function is used like this:

```
router.get('/', login.isAuthenticated(), controller.index);
```

So, middleware  will be called each time this route is called.

On your casem maybe, your middleware implementation may not inserted properly on route you want.